# OpenAPI generated schema request body display the default value instead of type

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

In using Pydantic with FastApi, I have an auto-generated Swagger UI.

Code for a sample Post method is as follows, with the pydantic model used included.

```
class StackInstanceInvocation(BaseModel):
    params: Dict[str, Any] = {}
    connection_credentials: ConnectionCredentials = None
    stack_infrastructure_template: str = "stackl"
    stack_application_template: str = "web"
    stack_instance_name: str = "default_test_instance"

@router.post('')
def post_stack_instance(stack_instance_invocation: StackInstanceInvocation):
    """Creates a stack instance with a specific name"""
    logger.info("[StackInstances POST] Received POST request")
    # check if SIT exists
    <SCRATCH>
```

For this, the UI displays the following:

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T11ao.png) and [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2GuS.png)

And when doing Try It Out:

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbqql.png)

However, when doing Try it Out, I'd prefer that the prefilled values not be the type but the indicated default values (namely, "stackl", "web" and "default_test_instance"). I went to the docs but have not found a way to do this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/#pydantic-schema_extra) may help you. Use `Field` or `Body` with example parameter